# Change icon state in WorkFlow

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

How can i change the icon of state in the workflow ? I search a lot in web and i only found how to change state machine but no state example.

[state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Ask.png)

Comment: See if https://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/2010/01/25/changing-the-icon-on-a-custom-activity-designer/ can help.

Comment: I found solution of my problem, if someone have the same problem, You can switch default icons use class WorkflowDesignerIcons.Activities.State